# Implementing `randoms`

Tags: haskell, random, reinventing-the-wheel

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) presents the `randoms` function.

I implemented it as follows:

```
-- randoms that takes a generator and returns an infinite sequence 
-- of values based on that generator
import System.Random

randoms' :: StdGen -> [Int]
randoms' g = num : randoms' gen
   where (num, gen) = random g
```

Please critique it.

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward. Easy to follow. But this is clearly some kind of fold.

```
randoms' = unfoldr (Just . random)
```

works nicely.